# I have to take in 5 names and number of times each was absent

Tags: java, arrays, position, max

I am able to find the max but not its position in the array to determine who it was, HELP?????
Thanks!!!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    String name[]=new String[5];
    String absent[]=new String[5];

    for(int i=0; i<=4; i++){

       name[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name");
       absent[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter absent total");}
       int absentint[] =new int[5];

       for(int i=0; i<=4; i++){
           absentint[i]=Integer.parseInt(absent[i]);
       }

       int j=0;
       int sum=0;
       int pos=0;
       while(j<=4){
          sum=sum+absentint[j];
          j++;
       }

       System.out.println(sum/absentint.length);
       int max=0;
       for(int l=0; l<=4; l++){
          if(absentint[l]>max){         
             max=absentint[l];
           }
        }

    System.out.println("Max= "+max);
    System.out.println("Position is "+ pos);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(absentint));
    int x= Collections.indexOfSubList(Arrays.asList(absentint), Arrays.asList(max));
```

Comment: format code properly. It didn't clearly show where loop start and end.

Comment: You should really read [this handy little guide](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/top-15-best-practices-for-writing-super-readable-code/) on coding practices since your code is barely readable. Question: why make absent[] a String array when you only use it for calculations? Use a simple int or float.

Comment: I was formatting the code and i realised something. There are no closing tags for "main" and the "big for loop" ??? Can you add their positions too.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this is the code that finds the max:

```
int max=0;
for(int l=0; l<=4; l++){
    if(absentint[l]>max)
    {
     max=absentint[l];
    }
}
```

So you just need to save the index as well as the value:

```
int max=0, index=0;
for(int l=0; l<=4; l++){
    if(absentint[l]>max)
    {
     max=absentint[l];
     index =l;
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't that just make the index always 1?

Comment: index = l not 1 (letter L jut not capital) - poor choice for a index variable but that's not my fault :)